# cypress-vite: heap out of memory

Tags: typescript, cypress, vite

I recently transformed my CRA project to use Vite.
Everything worked except for the Cypress e2e tests. I saw that the tests need preprocessing so I added `cypress-vite`.

Now every time I try to run a test, I get the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x100a26fe4 node::Abort() [/Users/orenurbach/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x100a2716c node::errors::TryCatchScope::~TryCatchScope() [/Users/orenurbach/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.1/bin/node]
 3: 0x100b75a98 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/orenurbach/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.1/bin/node]
 4: 0x100b75a2c v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/orenurbach/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.1/bin/node]
 5: 0x100cf9c98 v8::internal::Heap::GarbageCollectionReasonToString(v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason) [/Users/orenurbach/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.1/bin/node]
 6: 0x100cf87a4 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/orenurbach/.nvm/versions/node/v17.9.1/bin/node]
...
```

Here's my `cypress.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import vitePreprocessor from 'cypress-vite';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('file:preprocessor', vitePreprocessor());
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    specPattern: ['./tests/**/*.ts', './devops-tests/**/*.ts']
  },
});
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { viteCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs';

import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgrPlugin({
      svgrOptions: {
        icon: true
      }
    }),
    viteCommonjs()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true
  },
  preview: {
    port: 3000
  }
});
```

---

EDIT:
I added `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=32768` and the test finished running, but now with a different error:

```
createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Why would that happen?

Comment: Try to set the environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048` for example to increase the memory allocated to your node process. If you get the same error then there's a deeper issue.

Comment: @Luke-zhang-04 thanks! I updated my question with the new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `cypress-vite` was using my `vite.config` to build each test, and my `vite.config` loaded plugins that tried to compile the entire codebase (which makes references to `node_modules` as well).

To fix it, I created a new file called `vite.test.config.ts`, which had the bare minimum Vite config for React + helpful aliases for my test files:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@cypress': path.resolve(__dirname, './cypress'),
      '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    }
  }
});
```

and referenced it as a parameter in `cypress-vite`:

```
// cypress.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  setupNodeEvents(on) {
      on('file:preprocessor', vitePreprocessor(resolve(__dirname, './vite.test.config.ts')));
    },
})
```